# C# Using a timer to refresh textboxes from a datatable in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, datatable, textbox

I am attempting to build a leaderboard for a fishing tournament using WinForms in C#.  My idea is to populate text boxes with data from a SQL database that will be loaded into a datatable.  The Tournament has several sub-tournaments that will be displayed.

My WinForm has seven rows of textboxes so I need to display the first seven rows of the datatable for 40 seconds, then the next seven rows and so on until the table is empty. It would then run a query to refill the datatable for the next tournament and repeat the process.

The timer works because the form delays the correct length of time before filling, but I am stuck on how to make it refresh with the next seven rows.

Any help in getting going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
     private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TitleTxtBx.Text = "Redfish General Weight";
        SqlConnection KF = new SqlConnection("user id=--------;" +
                                  "password=--------;server=--------;" +
                                  "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
                                  "database=-------;" +
                                  "connection timeout=120");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RFFishWeight DESC) AS POS, Number, RFFName, RFLAName, RFFishWeight
                                                FROM RedFish
                                                WHERE Kayak LIKE 'no'
                                                AND RFFishWeight > 0
                                                ORDER BY RFFishWeight DESC, 
                                                TimeStamp DESC", KF);
        DataTable LBdt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(LBdt);          
        RnkTxtBx1.Text = LBdt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx1.Text = LBdt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx1.Text = LBdt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx1.Text = LBdt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx1.Text = LBdt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx2.Text = LBdt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx2.Text = LBdt.Rows[1][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx2.Text = LBdt.Rows[1][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx2.Text = LBdt.Rows[1][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx2.Text = LBdt.Rows[1][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx3.Text = LBdt.Rows[2][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx3.Text = LBdt.Rows[2][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx3.Text = LBdt.Rows[2][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx3.Text = LBdt.Rows[2][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx3.Text = LBdt.Rows[2][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx4.Text = LBdt.Rows[3][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx4.Text = LBdt.Rows[3][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx4.Text = LBdt.Rows[3][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx4.Text = LBdt.Rows[3][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx4.Text = LBdt.Rows[3][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx5.Text = LBdt.Rows[4][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx5.Text = LBdt.Rows[4][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx5.Text = LBdt.Rows[4][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx5.Text = LBdt.Rows[4][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx5.Text = LBdt.Rows[4][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx6.Text = LBdt.Rows[5][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx6.Text = LBdt.Rows[5][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx6.Text = LBdt.Rows[5][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx6.Text = LBdt.Rows[5][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx6.Text = LBdt.Rows[5][4].ToString();
        RnkTxtBx7.Text = LBdt.Rows[6][0].ToString();
        BTNbrTxtBx7.Text = LBdt.Rows[6][1].ToString();
        FNameTxtBx7.Text = LBdt.Rows[6][2].ToString();
        LNameTxtBx7.Text = LBdt.Rows[6][3].ToString();
        WhtTxtBx7.Text = LBdt.Rows[6][4].ToString();

        {
```

Comment: Consider using a limit offset practise, or delete the rows after displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll need to skip @n times 7 rows. You kan do this :

```
;with numberedtable as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RFFishWeight DESC) AS POS, Number, RFFName, RFLAName, RFFishWeight
  FROM RedFish
  WHERE Kayak LIKE 'no'
  AND RFFishWeight > 0
  ORDER BY RFFishWeight DESC, 
  TimeStamp DESC
)

select top 7 POS, Number, RFFName, RFLAName, RFFishWeight 
from numberedtable
where pos > 7 * @n
order by pos
```

Have a look at [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

And if you havent used Parameters before:

```
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", [pagenumber]);
```